# XSLT - XML Mapping with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

got a question. i have a payload (inbound) that is converted to XML (outbound). this is working fine, but then change request has been raised and needs to set condition from Inbound that if certain field E1EDK02 and child node QUALF has value of 012 field BELNR should be remove from the XML (outbound). how can i achieve this? hope you can help me.

below is the Inbound payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVOIC01>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
<EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
<TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
<IDOCTYP>INVOIC01</IDOCTYP>
<MESTYP>INVOIC</MESTYP>
<MESCOD>MM</MESCOD>
<SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
<SNDPRN>F4FARMINGP</SNDPRN>
<RCVPOR>SAPECP</RCVPOR>
<RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT>
<RCVPRN>ECPCLNT500</RCVPRN>
</EDI_DC40>
<E1EDK01SEGMENT="1">
<CURCY>AUD</CURCY>
<BSART>INVO</BSART>
<EIGENUINR>97000219214</EIGENUINR>
</E1EDK01>
<E1EDKA1SEGMENT="1">
<PARVW>RE</PARVW>
<PARTN/>
<NAME1>LANDMARKOPERATIONSRURALSERVICES</NAME1>
</E1EDKA1>
<E1EDKA1SEGMENT="1">
<PARVW>LF</PARVW>
<PARTN>0070090862</PARTN>
<NAME1>Tapex</NAME1>
</E1EDKA1>
<E1EDKA1SEGMENT="1">
<PARVW>AG</PARVW>
<PARTN>S2321000</PARTN>
<NAME1>GJ&amp;SSWhite</NAME1>
<STRAS>C/-LANDMARKWAGGA</STRAS>
<STRS2>53-55MOOROONGSTREET</STRS2>
<ORT01>WAGGAWAGGA</ORT01>
<REGIO>NSW</REGIO>
<PSTLZ>2665</PSTLZ>
</E1EDKA1>
<E1EDKA1SEGMENT="1">
<PARVW>WE</PARVW>
<NAME1>LANDMARK-ANAWBCOMPANY</NAME1>
<ORT01>53-55MOOROONG</ORT01>
<REGIO>ST</REGIO>
<PSTLZ>2650</PSTLZ>
</E1EDKA1>
<E1EDK02SEGMENT="1">
<QUALF>012</QUALF>
<BELNR>97160</BELNR>
</E1EDK02>
<E1EDK02SEGMENT="1">
<QUALF>099</QUALF>
<BELNR>1234566789</BELNR>
</E1EDK02>
<E1EDK03SEGMENT="1">
<IDDAT>012</IDDAT>
<DATUM>20151012</DATUM>
</E1EDK03>
<E1EDK03SEGMENT="1">
<IDDAT>028</IDDAT>
<DATUM>20151130</DATUM>
</E1EDK03>
<E1EDK04SEGMENT="1">
<MWSKZ>VAT</MWSKZ>
<MSATZ>10</MSATZ>
<MWSBT>509.80</MWSBT>
</E1EDK04>
<E1EDP01SEGMENT="1">
<MENGE>20.00</MENGE>
<MENEE>EA</MENEE>
<NETWR>254.90</NETWR>
<MATNR/>
<E1EDP02SEGMENT="1">
<QUALF>001</QUALF>
<BELNR>4501493907</BELNR>
<ZEILE/>
</E1EDP02>
<E1EDP19SEGMENT="1">
<QUALF>002</QUALF>
<IDTNR>MAX461</IDTNR>
<KTEXT>MAXITUBES4'6x150'</KTEXT>
</E1EDP19>
<E1EDP26SEGMENT="1">
<QUALF>003</QUALF>
<BETRG>5098.00</BETRG>
</E1EDP26>
<E1EDP04SEGMENT="1">
<MWSKZ>VAT</MWSKZ>
<MSATZ>10</MSATZ>
<MWSBT>509.80</MWSBT>
</E1EDP04>
</E1EDP01>
<E1EDS01SEGMENT="1">
<SUMID>006</SUMID>
<SUMME>509.80</SUMME>
</E1EDS01>
<E1EDS01SEGMENT="1">
<SUMID>010</SUMID>
<SUMME>5098.00</SUMME>
</E1EDS01>
<E1EDS01SEGMENT="1">
<SUMID>011</SUMID>
<SUMME>5607.80</SUMME>
</E1EDS01>
<E1EDS01SEGMENT="1">
<SUMID>020</SUMID>
</E1EDS01>
</IDOC>
</INVOIC01>
```

below is the current XSLT mapping used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>           
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|comment()">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add code to your question, not images. Thanks.

Comment: here is the input XML Payload

Comment: <INVOIC01>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
         <PARVW>LF</PARVW>
         <PARTN>0070090862</PARTN>
         <NAME1>Tapex</NAME1>
      </E1EDKA1>
      <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
         <QUALF>012</QUALF>
         <BELNR>97160</BELNR>
      </E1EDK02>
      <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
         <QUALF>099</QUALF>
         <BELNR>1234566789</BELNR>
      </E1EDK02>
      <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
         <IDDAT>012</IDDAT>
         <DATUM>20151012</DATUM>
      </E1EDK03>
   </IDOC>
</INVOIC01>

Comment: here is the existing XSLT mapping

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>   
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|comment()">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: You're current XML in your question is not well-formed. You have `<E1EDK02SEGMENT="1">` present, when I think it should be `<E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">`. Can you edit your question to correct this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the 'BELNR' element from 'E1EDK02' if the `QUALF` element is set to `012` then add this template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="E1EDK02[QUALF='012']/BELNR" />
```

Note that, it looks like your current XSLT is simply copying everything as is, with the exception of processing instructions and comments. Try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="E1EDK02[QUALF='012']/BELNR" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Actually, your current XSLT will only remove comments and processing instructions if they are under the document node, or root element, but I am not sure if that is intentional or not).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and comment!